# How To Play a Double array(includes the waves) using NAudio

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, naudio

I'm trying to play a double array that have waves. **but I don't know how can I do that**. I didn't found anything using google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class that derives from `ISampleProvider` which is a float based format. In the `Read` method, write the requested number of samples from your double array into the float buffer. The `WaveFormat` property should be an IEEE Float wave format with the sample rate and number of channels in your double array. Now you can use the SampleToWaveProvider to convert to an `IWaveProvider` class that can be played with WaveOut (n.b. future NAudio versions will not require this step, it is just that `ISampleProvider` is a relatively new addition).

Comment: I didn't understand how can I Implement the class. can you show some code?